# Mysql sum of every 5 data

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have table named eod where i tons of data by date. here is the schema of the table:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ticker     | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| entry_date | date        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| high       | float(10,2) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| low        | float(10,2) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| close      | float(10,2) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| vol        | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

here are few sample of data:

```
+----+-----------+------------+------+------+-------+--------+
| ID | ticker    | entry_date | high | low  | close | vol    |
+----+-----------+------------+------+------+-------+--------+
|  1 | x         | 2013-02-20 | 6.70 | 6.50 |  6.50 | 136500 |
|  2 | y         | 2013-02-24 | 6.60 | 6.40 |  6.40 | 174500 |
|  3 | z         | 2013-02-25 | 6.60 | 6.40 |  6.40 | 214000 |
|  4 | x         | 2013-02-26 | 6.50 | 6.30 |  6.40 | 238000 |
|  5 | x         | 2013-02-27 | 6.50 | 6.20 |  6.20 | 279000 |
|  6 | a         | 2013-02-28 | 6.20 | 6.00 |  6.00 | 260500 |
|  7 | x         | 2013-03-03 | 6.10 | 5.70 |  5.70 | 131000 |
|  8 | a         | 2013-03-04 | 6.10 | 5.80 |  6.00 | 150000 |
|  9 | x         | 2013-03-05 | 6.20 | 6.00 |  6.00 |  95000 |
| 10 | z         | 2013-03-06 | 6.10 | 6.00 |  6.00 |  84000 |
+----+-----------+------------+------+------+-------+--------+
```

I want to know how to get sum of every 5 vol, means from ID 1 to 5, then 6 to 10 .....continues by ticker.

sorry for creating confusion at the first time.

Comment: What are all the subqueries for?

Comment: first sub query is for finding the difference of current price from min price and second is for the price position formula is current-min/max-min

Comment: But you didn't want to find the difference!?!? Now I'm confused. And when you say 'within 3 months'... within 3 months of what?

Comment: Also, there's no way you want to use float for this. Change that to DECIMAL

Comment: Plus, this query is invalid - and even if it weren't it would return an empty result set in no way related to "3 months", so you're not quite telling us everything!

Comment: query is not invalid bro, i am getting right result. just couldnt find a way sum every 5 vol (1 to 5) then (6 to 10).

Comment: Homie, when the number of closing brackets is not equal to the number of opening brackets, the query will not work. Simples.

Comment: Do a subquery on your table; for ID, subtract 1, divide by 5 and truncate to integer so that IDs 1-5 produce 0, IDs 6-10 produce 1, IDs 11-15 produce 2 etc. (let's call this computed column IDGROUP). Perform your aggregate query on the result of your subquery grouping on the IDGROUP column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT SUM(vol) 
 FROM  (
               SELECT  vol, TRUNCATE(id/5,0) AS  id 
                FROM  eod) AS  t 
 GROUP  BY  id
```

Not tested but logic is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sum(column), floor((id-1)/5) + 1 as min_id
FROM table_name
GROUP BY min_id
```